# PHP Pull each metatags from index.php into different text boxes and replace changes made to tags in index.php

Tags: php

I'm trying to update metatags via a screen. I manage to pull the metatags into text boxes. After I change the tags in the text boxes, I don't know how to replace them in index.php when I click on Validate button. This is what I have for now:

```
    //Get metatags from index.php
    $files = 'index.php';
    $metatags = get_meta_tags($files);

    //echo these variables in text box
    $meta_viewport = $metatags['viewport'];
    $meta_author = $metatags['author'];
    $meta_keywords = $metatags['keywords'];
    $meta_description = $metatags['description'];

    <form name='formMetaTag' method="post" action="">
        <textarea name="meta_viewport" id="meta_viewport"><?php echo $meta_viewport; ?></textarea>
        <textarea name="meta_author" id="meta_author"><?php echo $meta_author; ?></textarea>
        <textarea name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords"><?php echo $meta_keywords; ?></textarea>
        <textarea name="meta_description" id="meta_description"><?php echo $meta_description; ?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="btnvalidate" value="Validate" id="btnvalidate" class="button"/>
    </form>
```

When I click on the validate button:

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnvalidate']))
    {

        $new_meta_viewport = $_POST['meta_viewport'];
        $new_meta_author = $_POST['meta_author'];
        $new_meta_keywords = $_POST['meta_keywords'];
        $new_meta_description = $_POST['meta_description'];

        //that's where im stuck, cant seem to get it to work
        $newmetas = str_replace($meta_viewport, $new_meta_viewport, $meta_viewport);


    }
```

Comment: Store the meta-tags outside of the code-files -- in a database (e.g. sqlite3) or a textfile.

Comment: Hey Tom, is there a way to just replace em tags directly..without going into db?

Comment: Self-modifying code is not a route I would stroll on while using php...; the easiest path is to use `serialize/unserialize` to/from a file (e.g. `meta_tags.data`) an array holding the meta-data